# False proof that simple groups are cyclic

Tags: group-theory

"Proof" of not cyclic $\implies$ not simple:
If $G$ is not cyclic, $\langle g \rangle$ is an abelian, and hence normal subgroup of $G$.

Doesn't this show every simple group is cyclic? What am I missing here?

Comment: An abelian subgroup isn't necessarily normal. That the group itself is abelian says nothing about how its elements behaves in relation with all the other elements in the group.

Comment: _Because_ an abelian subgroup is not necessarily normal...

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: @Arthur Answers should really be posted as answers, rather than comments.

Comment: Look at the group of six permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$.  The cyclic subgroup generated by the transposition that interchanges $1$ and $2$ and leaves $3$ fixed is not normal. Just look at its left and right cosets and you'll see that. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements of an abelian subgroup commute each other, but they don't have to commute with the rest of the group.

Comment: On the other hand, it is true that a nonabelian simple group must have trivial center.